# mysqli prepared statements - doyou still need to escape data?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am a bit confused about MYSQLI prepared statements. If you use prepared statements is the data automatically escaped or do you still have to do that.

I have attached some code below - based on this example is the data automatically escaped or do I have to do that also ?

```
        include("configi.php");

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO phx_userid (comp_name, email, password, user_sec_level, user_status, username, contact_name, comp_type, comp_system_option) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssiissss", $comp_name, $email_address, $password, $user_sec_level, $user_status, $email_address, $contact_name, $comp_type, $comp_system_option);

        // set parameters and execute



        $comp_name = $comp_name;
        $email_address = $email_address;
        $password =  password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $user_sec_level = 600;
        $user_status = 0;
        $contact_name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
        $comp_type = "fintrack";
        $comp_system_option = "standard";   

        $stmt->execute();
```

No errors - I just want to check if I am doing this right.

Comment: I should have noted that I am putting the strings through this

Comment: function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

Comment: prior to running the sql insert - is that the correct way to do it ?

Comment: No, you don’t have to escape. That’s what prepared statements are for :)  Keep in mind, though, that you should treat database info as tainted when you display it.